# Python: Why is my vectorization with numpy slower than a for cycle?

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, vectorization, montecarlo

I implemented a simple estimation of Pi with MonteCarlo as exercise and it seems that using a for cycle is faster than using only the numpy vectorization... There must be something that I haven't considered...

```
import numpy as np
import time

def method_1():
    start = time.time()
    
    N = 100_000 #Number of points
    total = 1/N
    N_run = 100 #Number of runs
    pi = np.zeros(N_run)
    x = np.random.rand(N, N_run)
    y = np.random.rand(N, N_run)

    pi = np.sum(x*x + y*y < 1, axis = 0)*4*total
    
    stop = time.time()
    
    return stop-start


def method_2():
    start = time.time()

    N = 100_000 #Number of points
    total = 1/N
    N_run = 100 #Number of runs
    pi = np.zeros(N_run)
    x = np.random.rand(N)
    y = np.random.rand(N)
    
    for i in range(N_run):
        pi[i] = np.sum(x*x + y*y<1)*4*total
        x = np.random.rand(N)
        y = np.random.rand(N)
        
    stop = time.time()
    
    return stop-start



N = 10
m1=np.zeros(N)
m2=np.zeros(N)

for i in range(N):
    m1[i] = method_1() 
    m2[i] = method_2()

print(f'Method 1: {np.mean(m1)} sec, Method 2: {np.mean(m2)} sec)
```

The output is:

> Method 1: 0.16888238191604615 sec, Method 2: 0.13313182592391967 sec

I was expecting a faster time for method_1...

Comment: Once you've pushed the 100000-iteration inner loops into NumPy, pushing the outer loop into NumPy doesn't really add much, and you had to allocate and work with 100 times as much memory to do it. (It might've changed the loop order, too.)

Comment: Often a modest number of iterations (here 100) on a complex, memory intensive calculations (100000 "points") is faster than the "vectorized" form.  I describe it crudely as a memory management issue, which can be computer dependent.  Times like .16 vs .13 are reasonable for that kind of tradeoff.